# Group members output = How to convert output shown as DistinguishedNames to Name

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am working on a script to return group members from specified group. This group belongs to a specific domain, but members (including groups as well)
may be from different domains. I've worked in a script that returns these members, but data is returned as DistinguishedName.

Example below

```
$grp = GROUPNAME1
    
$DNOUT = get-adgroup -identity $grp -properties member -server "DOMAIN.GROUP" | sort name | select-object -expandproperty -member

$DNOUT
```

```
output when I run this query
CN=AC1,OU=F1,DC=d1,DC=domain,DC=group
CN=GR30,OU=G4,DC=d3,DC=domain,DC=group
CN=AC23,OU=F2,DC=dXF,DC=domain,DC=group
CN=AC16,OU=F7,DC=d1,DC=domain,DC=group
```

I wish I could convert those outputs (Groups and Names from many domains included) to Displayname or Name attributes instead of DN.

I tried something different, but no results as well

```
try {Get-ADgroup -Identity $grp -Properties member -Server "mydomain.com" | select -object  -Expand Member | Get-ADObject -Properties * | SortName | select Name
} catch {
    $_.Exception.Referral
}
```

In this case, I am gettings Referral error from each member returned.
Get-ADObject : A referral was returned from the server

Comment: your question is unclear. you're showing how to query a group but the output you have does not correlate with that and what you want as a result is also unclear.

Comment: Hello, my output was just an example. In short when I run the script my output show lots of lines just with different group and user distinguishednames as intended, regardless of domain they belong.

Answer (score 0):

*Edit, yes you're right, my previous Get-ADGroup code didn't work as expected, but have confirmed the following (at least on my servers) produces the expected results.*

If you're after the names of the groups that are members of that group you should be able to use

```
$DNOUT = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $grp -server DOMAIN.GROUP | Select SamAccountName
```

which will output their Name rather than DistinguishedName values.

If you're after the users within that group (and within any groups that are members of it) you'd need to simply add the `-Recursive` parameter like this

```
$DNOUT = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $grp -server DOMAIN.GROUP -Recursive | Select SamAccountName
```

which will then output the list of SamAccountNames for the users that are part of that queried group, either directly or via a subgroup.

Comment: Hello, Ive just tried both, but only the group name I am looking for is returned. No members are shown.

Comment: Sorry, have tested my code properly now (rather than relying on old code where I've done it previously) and updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: No problem. I made a new test today but a new error is shown
"Get-AdGroupMember: The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error.